# I'm trying to synchronize my SQflite database with my app's home screen.The database already has 5 images placed by assests?

Tags: flutter

Bug switch does not recognize snapshot.connectionState. errors below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkmGV.png)

'Future<List<Task/1*/>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<List<Task/2*/>>?'.

```
'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
'List' is from 'dart:core'.
'Task/1/' is from 'package:emulador_flutter/components/task.dart' ('lib/components/task.dart').
'Task/2/' is from 'package:emulador_flutter/components//task.dart' ('lib/components//task.dart').

       future: TaskDao().findAll(),
                         ^
```

lib/screens/initial_screen.dart:37:33: Error: The type 'ConnectionState' is not exhaustively matched by the switch cases since it doesn't match 'ConnectionState.none'.
'ConnectionState' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart' ('../../Documents/flutter_windows_3.7.10-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/async.dart'). Try adding a default case or cases that match 'ConnectionState.none'.

```
     switch(snapshot.connectionState){
                     ^

Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
Where: Script 'C:\Users\marlo\Documents\flutter_windows_3.7.10-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1159

What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

    Process 'command 'C:\Users\marlo\Documents\flutter_windows_3.7.10-stable\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Try:

    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

BUILD FAILED in 30s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.